# pass a dictionary to copy module while using ansible api

Tags: python, ansible

I am using the ansible API to automate some task. the script will take the list of hosts as arguments

using a local python library will generate some content unique for the host and then a play is created using the copy module and want to pass a dictionary key to the content to avoid creating a temporary file on the control ansible host

somehow the copy module does not expand correctly the variable `inventory_hostname` or even `ansible_nodename`

I think i have tried everything with single quotes, without, with/without curly brackets.

```
from custom lib import generate_content
file_content = {}
for hostname in hostnames:
    file_content[hostname] = generate_content(hostname)

loader = DataLoader()
passwords = { }

context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags={}, listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='ssh',
                    module_path=None, forks=100,  private_key_file=None,
                    ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None,become=True,
                    become_method='sudo',become_user='root', verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None)


Inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=my_inv)

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=Inventory, version_info=CLI.version_info(gitinfo=False))

play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = 'all',
        gather_facts = 'yes',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{inventory_hostname}}'))),
            dict(action=dict(module='copy', content=file_content[inventory_hostname], dest='/etc/content', backup='yes'))
         ]
    )

play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)


tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
              inventory=Inventory,
              variable_manager=variable_manager,
              loader=loader,
              passwords=passwords,
              stdout_callback="default",
          )
    result = tqm.run(play)
finally:

    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
```

the debug module does correctly expands correctly the `inventory_hostname` variable but not when passed as a key to the contents or the copy module.

is there a way to achieve this? 
if i put the inventory_hostname without single_quotes i get this error:

```
    dict(action=dict(module='copy', content=file_content[inventory_hostname], dest='/etc/content', backup='yes'))
NameError: name 'inventory_hostname' is not defined
```

if I use single or double quotes i get a KeyError:

```
    dict(action=dict(module='copy', content=file_content["inventory_hostname"], dest='/etc/content', backup='yes'))
KeyError: u'inventory_hostname'
```

the fact that there are curly brackets does not change the issue and the errors.

using python 2.7

Comment: Make sure to upgrade to python 3 asap https://www.anaconda.com/end-of-life-eol-for-python-2-7-is-coming-are-you-ready/

Comment: how this can fix my problem?